# FIFO Aging Simulation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to simulate a backlog of cases by age.

Assumptions:

1. `FIFO: (First In First Out)`: This means we will always prioritize cases in the `4+` bucket then move to the bucket to it's left and so on. This means current day `Inflow` has last priority.
2. `Productivity = 1,000 = Constant`: The most that can be worked in a single day is 1,000
3. Before the simulation begins we have `1'000 aged 1 day`, `750 aged 2 days`, `500 aged 3 days`, & `250 aged 4 days`

---

Given this information, I believe it is possible to input any **Inflow** and have the buckets complete themselves. I cannot figure out what equations to use to populate the desired result though.

I have tried a series of `SUM`, `SUMIF`, `IF`, and checking if the differences between a bucket and productivity is negative (all unsuccessful).

---

In Photo, the buckets for each day represent the end of day age of everything. Towards the end, when backlog is cleared, all buckets show 0 since the inflow is less then the productivity I.E. cleared that day and never gets to actually age. The inflow column essentially represents 0 days old

*Gray columns are locked*

[image]

**How can I correctly populate the buckets and produce no negatives?**

Comment: I'm not clear on your process. On any given day are you "working" the 1000 oldest units?. Do those get removed from the table or do you tote those up somewhere? For the units that don't get worked, do they get carried down one row (to the next day's work) and one column to the right (to give them one more day of aging)?

Comment: That all seems correct. On the first day they will work 1000 starting from the right bucket and keep moving left until they have reached the max productivity. The next day the remainder of the work to be done less productivity (1000) should be distributed to the appropriate buckets. Each day it is not cleared it will move up in age by 1 day. Once they are worked they fall off. This is only tracking backlog (things not worked) @xidgel

Comment: It seems logical to start working equations from 4+ bucket then 3, 2, 1  but just can’t get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
In H4: =MAX(SUM(G3:H3-$A$3),0)
In G4: =MAX(SUM(F3:H3)-$A$3-SUM(H4),0)
In F4: =MAX(SUM(E3:H3)-$A$3-SUM(G4:H4),0)
In E4: =MAX(SUM(E3:H3)+D4-$A$3-SUM(F4:H4),0)
```

Then fill down.
In those formulas `$A$3` is the productivity. Hope that helps.

Comment: very elegant answer

Answer (score 1):

**Step1: Guiding principle for each bucket:**

If a bucket has more than the remaining productivity for that bucket for that day, then (BUCKETVALUE - REMAININGUNITS), else 0.

We will deploy this IF logic in steps 3 - 6.

Step 3 defines what is REMAININGUNITS for each bucket, which is again used in subsequent steps 3 - 6

**Step2:**
Now let's define REMAININGUNITS as the amount of units that can be cleared for the day for a bucket

```
So, REMAININGUNITS for Bucket 4 is PRODUCTIVITY, i.e. potentially all of A3 can be used to clear Bucket 4                               
    =$A$3                           
Remaining units for bucket 3 = PRODUCTIVITY - Actual Reduction in Bucket 4                              
    =($A$3-(H3-H4))                         
Remaining units for bucket 2 = PRODUCTIVITY - Actual Reduction in Bucket 4 - Actual Reduction in Bucket 3                               
    =($A$3-(H3-H4)-(G3-G4))                         
Remaining units for bucket 1 = PRODUCTIVITY - Actual Reduction in Bucket 4 - Actual Reduction in Bucket 3 - Actual Reduction in Bucket 2                                
    =($A$3-(H3-H4)-(G3-G4)-(F3-F4))
```

**Step3:**
Clear as much of 4th bucket as possible,

`H4=IF(H3>$A$3,H3-$A$3,0)`

**Step4:**
Clear as much of 3rd bucket as possible,

`G4=IF(G3>($A$3-(H3-H4)),G3-($A$3-(H3-H4)),0)`

**Step5:**
Clear as much of 2nd bucket as possible,

`F4=IF(F3>($A$3-(H3-H4)-(G3-G4)),F3-($A$3-(H3-H4)-(G3-G4)),0)`

**Step6:**
Clear as much of (1st bucket + INFLOW) as possible,

`E4=IF(E3+D3>($A$3-(H3-H4)-(G3-G4)-(F3-F4)),E3+D3-($A$3-(H3-H4)-(G3-G4)-(F3-F4)),0)`

**Step7:**
Fill the formulaes from Row 4 to the remanining rows